# Using middleware in laravel5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4, middleware

Actually, i'm new to `laravel`. I'm trying to make Authenticating Users manually I have a problem that there's no middleware work anyone know what's the problem 
it should redirect to the homepage but it doesn't ...

here's for login

```
public function __construct(){


    $this->middleware('auth')->except(['index','show' ]);
}
```

and that for posts

```
public function __constructor(){
    $this->middleware('guest')->except(['destroy' ]);
}
```

Comment: in route you have mention middleware?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your middleware in app/Http/Kernel.php and this file have examples,then add the middleware in route like this `Route::group(['middleware' => 'your middleware's name'], function () {....}`